# I'd like a global mode-line in my frame

Tags: customize, mode-line, powerline

### A previous comment...

In the following I'm calling *mode-line* to the `mode-line` itself or any of its variations/replacements (e.g. `powerline`)

## Statement of the *problem*

In the next picture, you can see the behaviour of the mode-line in my emacs session, when there is a single window in the frame.

[image: single-window-view]

Except by a problem in my configuration of =diminish= package, it has the information I want.

The problems is that whenever I split the window, I lost useful information... since there is a mode-line for each window. See for example the figure below!

[image: split-window-view]

It gets worst as there are more windows in my frame.

## What I would like

I'd like the mode-line to behave as the `menu-line`:

- there is only one per frame,
- the content depends on the *active* buffer

### Question(s)

Is it possible to hack such behaviour? How? Does anyone try it? ... Or know a package?

I'm not a programmer myself, but I'd appreciate even a hint of where to start hacking!

Answer (score 3):

The mode-line is a feature implemented in the C code with lots of ad-hoc special code deep in the redisplay and window-handling code for it.  This code does not support "one mode-line per frame" at all.

So if you want to get a single mode-line shared among various windows, your best bet will be something like:

- Set `mode-line-format` to nil so that windows don't have any mode-line any more.
- Create a *side* window which will hold your mode-line.  Make it display some new buffer which you could call `*mode-line*`.
- Add hooks to update this `*mode-line*` buffer whenever necessary.

I don't know of any package which does that currently.

Comment: Thank you for the answer... I like your suggestion! Could you elaborate a bit more on the (possible) execution of the steps?